# android layout not displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I have trouble displaying the layout of my main activity :

I create an ActivityA with an ImageView.

In onCreate(), I launch an AsyncTask, which retrieves content from Internet, and opens an ActivityB.

When I launch my application, it displays ActivityB right away.

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyTask mytask = new MyTask();
        mytask.execute();

    }
```

}

My MainActivity xml file is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_page" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/marker_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ProgressBar is used to show the loading process of the AsyncTask.

thanks for helping

Comment: Show where/how you are starting activity B. Most likely, directly after calling the task

Comment: Show AsyncTask code.

Comment: Which is the Activity that does not show its layout? A or B?

Comment: @Joseph82 it's ActivityA that doesn't show.

Comment: @codeMagic, I start ActivityB in onPostExecute(), after the network call is performed in doInBackground()

Comment: Then show the task class as someone else stated

Comment: @saloua it seems strange, since it should work, also if your are using the `RelativeLayout` in the wrong way. It doesn't require any orientation parameter, and you should use others xml properties in order to locate your views child inside the `RelativeLayout`. Try to use a `LineaLayout`

Comment: Show us the entire code of MyTask .class and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: post your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MyTask mytask = new MyTask();
            mytask.execute();
        }
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // code for retrieve contents from Internet
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // cancel ProgressBar and start activity B here like
            Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            // showing ProgressBar
        }

    }
```

don't forgot to mention A activity as a launcher.
I hope it will help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... This is what I am actually doing... but it still don't seem to work... Could it be a problem of temporization ? the Asynctask executes so quickly that we don"t see the first layout.